# arr.map not looping actual values

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Been away from code for a few years and I'm giving it another chance. I'm scraping `option`s data from a `select` element using Puppeteer. Most of the data that I need is contained within the `option`s elements themselves, however, a status icon is also assigned to each `option` contained in `div> abbr > img` structure outside of the `div > select`.

**The Code**

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

(async function () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: "new",
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  page.on("console", async (e) => {
    const args = await Promise.all(e.args().map((a) => a.jsonValue()));
    console.log(...args);
  });

  await page.goto("https://reports.housefacks.com/index.cfm?event=login");

  await page.type("#email", "email@gmail.com");
  await page.type("#password", "password");

  const loginBtn = 'input[type="submit"]';
  await page.click(loginBtn);

  const myReports = 'a[href="index.cfm?event=inspector.myReports&init=true"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(myReports);
  await page.click(myReports);

  const report = 'a[href="index.cfm?event=report.setupstep1&reportID=80988"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(report);
  await page.click(report);

  await page.goto(
    "https://reports.housefacks.com/index.cfm?event=report.setupstep4&reportID=80988"
  );

  const abbr = 'abbr[title="Click here to add a new Concern"] > a[href="#"]';

  await page.waitForSelector(abbr);
  await page.click(abbr);


  const concernsData = await page.$$eval("option", (options) => {
    let obj = {};
    return options.map((i) => {
      obj = {
        name: i.text,
        text: i.getAttribute("thetext"),
        value: i.getAttribute("value"),
      };
      return obj;
    });
  });

  const myValues = concernsData.map((i) => i.value);

  await page.$eval(
    "#savedconcern",
    (select, arr, data) => {
      let dataCopy = [...data];
      
      arr.map((v) => {
        const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll("#iconcorral img")]
          .map(
            (i) => !i.getAttribute("src").includes("bw") && i.getAttribute("id")
          )
          .filter((i) => i != false);
        
        dataCopy.map((d) => {
          ids.map((i) => {
            d.icon = i;
          });
        });

        select.value = v;

        const event = new Event("change");
        select.dispatchEvent(event);
      });

      return dataCopy;
    },
    myValues,
    concernsData
  );
})();
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    name: '----------',
    text: '',
    value: '0',
  },
  {
    name: 'No numbers visible',
    text: 'There was no house number that could be seen from the street',
    value: '662204',
    icon: 'newconcern_saftey'
  },
  {
    name: 'Condominium',
    text: 'Property is a condominium',
    value: '662206',
    icon: 'newconcern_comment'
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

**Current Output**

```
    [
          {
            name: '----------',
            text: '',
            value: '0',
            icon: 'newconcern_comment'
          },
          {
            name: 'No numbers visible',
            text: 'There was no house number that could be seen from the street.'
            value: '662204',
            icon: 'newconcern_comment'
          },
          {
            name: 'Condominium',
            text: 'Property is a condominium.'
            value: '662206',
            icon: 'newconcern_comment'
          },
          {
            ...
          }
        ]
```

For some reason the map for the `ids` is not lining up with the actual values. it seems to zoom right to the end and assigns `icon: 'newconcern_comment'` for each entry. I've tried an using a long form `for(let obj = 1; obj < dataCopy.length; obj ++) { ... }`  loop and `for ..in` with no success. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Expected and current are the same? Don't use `.map` for side effects, and don't reassign to `let obj` repeatedly--create new objects at each iteration, or that array will be a bunch of copies of the same object. In general, try not to mutate/reassign your data, just generate new structures functionally to avoid aliasing bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit dangerous:

```js
dataCopy.map((d) => {
   ids.map((i) => {
       d.icon = i;
   });
});
```

If that's what you really want to do then use `.forEach()` and not `.map()`.  Both of these "array helper functions" are loops over the array, the difference being that `.forEach()` runs the callback on each element of the array but does not return anything, whereas `.map()` runs the callback on each element of the array, gets the RETURN VALUE of each, and adds it to a NEW ARRAY of elements that gets returned.

That is:  `d.forEach(.....)` does not return any value, whereas `d.map(.....)` returns a new array with the return value of each invocation of the callback.

```js
let foo = [1, 2, 3].map(i => i * 2);
console.log(foo); // outputs: [2, 4, 6]

let bar = [1, 2, 3].forEach(i => i * 2);
console.log(bar); // outputs: undefined
```

Ultimately, if you are calling `.map()` but not using its resulting returned array, you shouldn't be using `.map()`.

Additionally, it is often not a good idea to make changes to the source array when using the "array helper functions".  You *can* do it, but frequently people end up with strange issues if they add or remove elements to the array.  If you want to modify the array, I recommend using a standards `for` or `for...in` loop.